# Using SAS EG to get percentages

Tags: sas

Hopefully this is a relatively easy question for someone to be able to help me with. I am a newbie to SAS (and programming). I have a dataset that has numerous variables each measuring time spent at different activities, with approx. 18,000 unique entries. I need to get the percentage that each of these variables contribute to the total amount of time spent. I know how to do this jut not how to make SAS do it. Screenshot of some of the variables below along with the total at the far right. Please let me know if you need anything else

[screenshot of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6gUG.png)

Thank you both, DomPazz and momo1644,  for these solutions. These are both helping to contribute to my understanding of SAS. However given that both your solutions have covered doing this on a row by row basis I was obviously unclear about what I am actually trying to achieve. I am trying to get a total for each of the variables and then find the percentage that that total contributes to the overall total. If I was doing this 'by hand' it would be v1_total/overall-total * 100/1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this for each row -- use a data step to update the value of the variables dividing by the total.

```
data want;
set have;
var1 = var1 / total;
var2 = var2 / total;
/*repeat as needed*/
run;
```

Replace `var1`, `var2`, `total` with your actual variable names.

A SAS Data Step operates on each record in the data set.  It has an implicit loop across all records.  So you write the formula you want and it executes it across the table.

If you want new values for the percentages, then the code is similar:

```
data want;
set have;
var1_p = var1 / total;
var2_p = var2 / total;
/*repeat as needed*/
run;
```

Here instead of updating the value in `var1`, we are creating a new variable `var1_p` to hold the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS Enterprise Guide you  can do this either by:

- Writing the code
- Or Using the Query Builder (Point and Click)

**Option 1: SASCode**

```
data have;
input id $ v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 total;
datalines;
A 1 2 3 4 5 15
B 1 2 3 4 10 20
C 0 0 0 0 15 15
D 1 0 1 0 2 4
;
RUN;
DATA want1;
set have;
v1pcnt=v1/total;
v2pcnt=v2/total;
v3pcnt=v3/total;
v4pcnt=v4/total;
v5pcnt=v5/total;
format v1pcnt percent10.2 v2pcnt percent10.2 v3pcnt percent10.2 v4pcnt percent10.2 v5pcnt percent10.2;
drop v1 v2 v3 v4 v5;
run;
```

**Option 2: EG Query Builder**

- Right click on your source table and select "Query Builder"
- Click on the calculated field to create a new filed for each of your variables
  [image: Step2]
- Choose advanced expression and paste the code from option 1 for each variable: `v1/total`
- Click next and provide a column name "v2pcnt" and format "percent10.2"
  [image: Step3]
- Click finish and repeat the steps for the other variables, when ready click RUN then the table will be created.

[image: step4]